# ionizing radiation and energy

Tags: energy, radiation

At the website "How Stuff Works" an article ([radiation sickness](http://science.howstuffworks.com/radiation-sickness.htm)) states that when radiation knocks an electron from an atom, energy (specifically 33 electron volts) is released which heats up the surrounding tissues (in an organism) and can damage DNA. But in Chem 101, I learned that energy is required* to remove an electron from an atom, hence the name ionization energy. Can you explain how energy is *released* when ionizing radiation strikes an atom?

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term "released" is applied a bit too liberally here:

The underlying idea should be the following: As per your Chem 101 course, you need energy to ionize an atom. But the atom will not stay ionized, it will immediately attract an electron again. This electron will then release energy - the ionization energy. Since the original energy to ionize the atom does not come from the surrounding tissue but from the radiation, the process has in fact added energy to the system (at the expense of energy of the radiation). This additional energy has to go somewhere - and it will most likely be released as heat.

So I think that what they mean to say is that by ionization, energy is transferred from the radiation to the tissue, which indeed results in heating of the tissue.

In addition of course, electron bonds can be destroyed, new and unwanted bonds be formed if the ionized atom bonds with a new atom, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ionization is not just to do with knocking electrons out of atoms and molecules.  If there is enough energy available the bonds between molecules can be broken to form ions.

Energies of 33 eV are equivalent to the extreme UV band of the electromagnetic spectrum.  Energies of this magnitude can break up water molecules and produce free radicals (reactive species) of which the hydroxyl radical $OH^-$ is considered one of the most dangerous.  It is like very reactive oxygen.  This radical reacts with organic molecules, proteins, nucleic acids and cell membranes and damages them.  However it is damage to the DNA which can cause mutations and cancer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the figure of 33eV comes from [the definition of ionising radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation) i.e. electromagnetic radiation with an energy above around 10 to 33 eV (the boundary is somewhat vaguely defined). However gamma radiation from radioactive sources can be much, much higher energy than this.

The mechanism is that a gamma photon is absorbed by an atom and produces an ion and a free electron. The energy of the free electron is the energy of the original gamma photon minus the binding energy of the electron in the atom and the energy of the free electron can be many keV. This is far greater than molecular binding energies, and the result is that the electron rips apart any molecules it hits potentially killing cells along the way.

The article you cite is somewhat vaguely worded, but I think the phrase:

> The release of the electron produces 33 electron volts (eV) of energy

means that the gamma radiation produces a free electron with an energy of 33 eV or more - usually much more!